# XSLT can't get xml child elements

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have the following xsl stylesheet and xml but I can't get  the  elements in the xml parent node in xsl template match is not working, I can't get table and costumer nodes from xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <HTML>
            <HEAD>
                <TITLE>Title</TITLE>
            </HEAD>
            <BODY>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/parent"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="costumer">
        <p>Costumer</p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="@type"/>
        <xsl:variable name="height" select="@height"/>
        <xsl:variable name="width" select="@wdth"/>
        <xsl:variable name="margin-top" select="@margin-top"/>
        <xsl:variable name="margin-left" select="@margin-left"/>
        <table id="{$name}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" style="margin-top:{$margin-top}; margin-left:{$margin-left}">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]/*" mode="th"/>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="th">
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
        </th>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:variable name="texttd" select="@text"/>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$texttd"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And below is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>
    <table name="region1" type="td" wdth="0" height="0" margin-top="1" margin-left="122">
        <td margin-top="0" margin-left="152" width="36" height="13" font-family="Arial-BoldMT" font-size="16" font-weight="0" text="??&quot;?" line-height="300" is-visible="True" color="#0A4462" />
        <Text name="region1" type="Title" wdth="0" height="0" margin-top="7" margin-left="138">
            <Title margin-top="0" margin-left="14" width="36" height="13" font-family="Arial-BoldMT" font-size="16" font-weight="0" text="??&quot;?" line-height="300" is-visible="True" color="#0A4462" />
        </Text>
    </table>
    <table name="region1" type="td" wdth="0" height="0" margin-top="1" margin-left="122">
        <td margin-top="0" margin-left="152" width="36" height="13" font-family="Arial-BoldMT" font-size="16" font-weight="0" text="??&quot;?" line-height="300" is-visible="True" color="#0A4462" />
        <Text name="region1" type="Title" wdth="0" height="0" margin-top="7" margin-left="138">
            <Title margin-top="0" margin-left="14" width="36" height="13" font-family="Arial-BoldMT" font-size="16" font-weight="0" text="??&quot;?" line-height="300" is-visible="True" color="#0A4462" />
        </Text>
    </table>
    <table name="region1" type="td" wdth="0" height="0" margin-top="1" margin-left="122">
        <td margin-top="0" margin-left="152" width="36" height="13" font-family="Arial-BoldMT" font-size="16" font-weight="0" text="??&quot;?" line-height="300" is-visible="True" color="#0A4462" />
        <Text name="region1" type="Title" wdth="0" height="0" margin-top="7" margin-left="138">
            <Title margin-top="0" margin-left="14" width="36" height="13" font-family="Arial-BoldMT" font-size="16" font-weight="0" text="??&quot;?" line-height="300" is-visible="True" color="#0A4462" />
        </Text>
    </table>
    <costumer></costumer>
    <costumer></costumer>
</parent>
```

Comment: Does your stylesheet have `</xsl:stylesheet>` at the end?

Comment: are you getting an error? what do you want to get and what do you get instead?

Comment: I don't get an error  I just get html without tables so I want to have <table></table><table></table><table></table><p></p><p></p> in <body></body> but instead of that I'm getting only the texts in td in <body> like <body> text1td text2td text3td</body>

Comment: yes it has </xsl:stylesheet> I forgot to put it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic templates like `<xsl:template match="/*/*/*" >` get a higher priority. It seems the number of slashes `/` in an expression count towards the priority.

I think you should increase the priority of the templates you want by making the XPath more specific

```
<xsl:template match="/parent/table">
<xsl:template match="/parent/costumer">
```

This will still not work for the `costumer`, so you need to move it to the end of the stylesheet, because items at the end are preferred in case of equal priorities.

You could also reduce the priority on the generic items explicitly like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*" priority="-1">
```

As an alternative you can increase the priority of the items you want explicitly:

```
<xsl:template match="table" priority="5">
```

Other that that I would need the full expected output to see if that all helps building the solution you're looking for.

BTW: I guess you want *customer* instead of *costumer*.

Comment: @Arthur: if you consider this as helpful, you can upvote by clicking the `^` icon next to the big number. If you consider this as the accepted answer, you can click the checkmark below that number. It will help others focus on unanswered questions. Both you and me will gain reputation by doing so. Thank you.